# angular sortable with model data from json

Tags: json, angularjs

I wanna use angular sortable on my app. But my model is dynamically populated from several json files with `$http.get()` function. All that ngSortable see from the model is just an empty array. And it won't get the new data from the JSON file. Is there any workaround for this?

```js
$scope.jsons = ["data1.json", "data2.json"];
$scope.abc = [];

angular.forEach($scope.jsons, function(value, key){
 $http.get(value).success (function(data){
  $scope.abc.push(data);
 });
});

$scope.sortableOptions = {
  accept: function (sourceItemHandleScope, destSortableScope) {return true}
};
```

```html
<div ng-model="abc" as-sortable="sortableOptions">
 <div ng-repeat="x in abc" as-sortable-item>
  <div as-sortable-item-handle>{{x.name}}</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with ng-sortable: everything worked fine with static data but not with JSON data that come asynchronous from $http.get().

There are two solutions:

1. Leave the controller as it and, in the html part, replace both occurrences of "abc" with "$parent.abc"
2. Instead of directly access the 'abc' array, use an intermediate object, like this:

   ```
   $scope.tmpObject = {};
   $scope.tmpObject.abc=[];
   ...
   $http.get(value).success (function(data){
       $scope.tmpObject.abc.push(data);
   });
   ```

   ...

   ```
   <div ng-model="tmpObject.abc" as-sortable="sortableOptions">
       <div ng-repeat="x in tmpObject.abc" as-sortable-item>
           <div as-sortable-item-handle>{{x.name}}</div>
       </div>
   </div>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

use [service $q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)
like

```js
//first make a factory using $q

yourappname.factory("factoryname",function($http, $q){
    var _getDetails=function(value){

        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.get(value).then(function(modal){

            deferred.resolve(modal);
        });

        return deferred.promise;

    };
  return  {
    _getDetails:_getDetails
  
};
  });

// then in your controller use this factory

$scope.jsons = ["data1.json", "data2.json"];
$scope.abc = [];


/**angular.forEach($scope.jsons, function(value, key){
 $http.get(value).success (function(data){
  $scope.abc.push(data);
 });
});
***/
angular.forEach($scope.jsons, function(value, key){
           var promiseData= factoryname._getDetails(value);
           promiseData.then(function(result){
           if(result.data)
            {
              $scope.abc.push(result.data);
              
            }
              
           });
});                  
$scope.sortableOptions = {
  accept: function (sourceItemHandleScope, destSortableScope) {return true}
};
```

```html
<div ng-model="abc" as-sortable="sortableOptions">
 <div ng-repeat="x in abc" as-sortable-item>
  <div as-sortable-item-handle>{{x.name}}</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion using the $q service. But nothing changes at all. All the same behavior :|, the ngSortable still won't see the newly loaded json data